# What's wrong with your sample size $\times$ the chance that one of your samples is albino?

Tags: probability

Please see the embolded phrase below in footnote *. Ellenberg multiplied the $50$ experimental subjects by the chance of albinism = $50 \times \color{limegreen}{\dfrac{1}{20000}} = \dfrac{1}{400}$. Why isn't this "exactly right"?

> But here’s the bad news: the reductio ad unlikely, unlike its Aristotelian
> ancestor, is not logically sound in general. It leads us into its own absurdities.
> Joseph Berkson, the longtime head of the medical statistics division at the
> Mayo Clinic, who cultivated (and loudly broadcast) a vigorous skepticism
> about methodology he thought shaky, offered a famous example
> demonstrating the pitfalls of the method. Suppose you have a group of $\color{red}{\text{fifty
> experimental subjects}}$, who you hypothesize (H) are human beings. You
> observe (O) that one of them is an albino. Now, albinism is extremely rare,
> $\color{limegreen}{\text{affecting no more than one in twenty thousand people}}$. So given that H is
> correct, the chance you’d find an albino among your $\color{red}{\text{fifty}}$ subjects is quite
> small, less than 1 in 400,* or 0.0025. So the p-value, the probability of
> observing O given H, is much lower than .05.
>        We are inexorably led to conclude, with a high degree of statistical
> confidence, that H is incorrect: the subjects in the sample are not human
> beings.

> *As a good rule of thumb, you can figure that each of the $\color{red}{\text{fifty}}$  subjects contributes a $\color{limegreen}{1/20,000}$ chance of finding al albino in the sample, yielding $1/400$; **this isn't exactly right [emphasis mine]**, but is usually close enough in cases like this one, where the result is very close to 0.

Ellenberg, *How Not to Be Wrong* (2014), p 136. I added the colors. The book's monochrome.

Comment: One way to think about why it is not *exactly* correct is to consider a sample size of more than 20,000.  Would that give you a probability of more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the correct value would be $1 - \left(1 - \frac1{20000}\right)^{50},$ which you can think of as $1$ minus the chance that all $50$ people are not albino. (assuming independence)

When the probability is small (and $\frac1{20000}$ is pretty small so it's pretty justified here) you can use the first order Taylor approximation $(1 - x)^n \approx 1 - nx$ to simplify this to $1 - \left(1 - 50\cdot \frac1{20000}\right) = 50 \cdot \frac1{20000}.$

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is the probability of albinism and you have $n$ people, then the chance that none of the $n$ people are albino is $(1-p)^n$ and therefore the chance that at least one person is albino is $1-(1-p)^n$. The calculation in Ellenberg's footnote  is $np$.  As you can see, these 2 expressions aren't exactly equal, but they are pretty close when $np$ is small, as Ellenberg notes.